# Check if data exist before accessing to prevent accessing undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am using React to access some data coming back from an API. The following code works but seems really repetitive. Is there a better way of doing this so that I dont accidentally get an error by accessing null property?

```
renderComicList() {
    var detail = this.props.seriesDetail;

    if (!detail || !detail[0] || !detail[0].comics || !detail[0].comics.items) {
        return (
            <div>No data exist (yet)</div>
        )
    }

    if (detail[0].comics.items.length === 0) {
        return (
            <div>No Comic Found</div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {detail[0].comics.items[0]}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you can also avoid the first condition by using [lodash/has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has)

Comment: @matt93: Given the `lodash` tag on the question, an answer calling out how `_.has` solves this (and it does) would be good!

Answer (score 2):

Not if each of those conditions can exist, other than using error handling:

```
renderComicList() {
    var items;

    try {
        items = this.props.seriesDetail[0].comics.items;
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
    if (!items) {
        return <div>No data exist (yet)</div>;
    }

    if (!items.length) {
        return (
            <div>No Comic Found</div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {items[0]}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've added handling for two cases there that your original code didn't handle: `detail[0].comics` exists but `detail[0].comics.items` doesn't, and `detail[0].comics.items` exists but has no `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here's my answer - assumably you are working with some `array`, because you are testing if detail[0] (why is it not plural if it's an array?) exists. Then you test if detail[0] contain some other nested array. If both tests pass, you render some item.

Well, this is definitely `not how you work with arrays` in React.. I assume you'd like to do something like this:

```
import has from 'lodash/has'

renderDetail(detail) {
  return has(detail, 'comics.items') && detail.comics.items.length
  ? (
    <div>
      { detail.comics.items.map(item => item) }
    </div>
  )
  : (
    <div>
      No Comic Found
    </div>
  )
}

render() {
  const details = this.props.seriesDetail

  return details.length
  ? (
    <div>
      { details.map(detail => this.renderDetail(detail)) }
    </div>
  )
  : (
    <div>
      No data exist (yet)
    </div>
  )
}
```

Both of your little tests are included and items of nested arrays are displayed. I'm not sure if this answers your question directly, but I strongly recommend using array mapping and avoiding the approach you used (testing arrays for [0] element).